# Initialize dB(sqlite3) with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to create a dB for testing purposes and I would like initialize it with "some" users.

### The "intended" code is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

manager = Manager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)

    def __init__(self, user = None, email = None):
        name = self.__tablename__
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        for i in range(100):
            user = User('user%d' % i, 'someone@example.com')
            db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    
    def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

The call  `usr_db = User()` generates `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

The question is , when during construction the class is "ready" to be called recursively to avoid the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating test users inside the model class is the wrong way to do it.  This is going to recursively call `__init__()` if you instantiate a `User()` instance inside `__init__()`.  A better place would be inside a unittest `setUp()` method.

However, if you really want to do this, you could guard against instantiating the users more than once like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)

    _test_users_initialised = False

    def _initialise_test_users(self):
        if self._test_users_initialised:
            return
        self.__class__._test_users_initialised = True

        for i in range(100):
            user = User('user%d' % i, 'someone@example.com')
            db.session.add(user)

    def __init__(self, user = None, email = None):
        name = self.__tablename__
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        self._initialise_test_users()
        db.session.commit()
```